# Pass a route parameter when return View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, routes

i have a web application in Razor-MVC and the thing is this:

I have an Action that goes like every actions in MVC {controller}/{action}/{id}
Now... i have another action, that needs to return this view: `return View("Xview")` with the Model View too. The model view its not a problem, but the route i see when i do the `return View("Xview")` its like {controller}/{action} without the id... and i need that id in my route.
I know i can make a `return RedirecToAction("Xview", new { id = idX })` but i need to use `return View(...)`

Edit:

The main issue because i need to return the view is because the ModelView in this action fills with temporal data... and in the Xview action, this ModelView its called from database and if i return RedirectToAction then the temporal data is lost, thats why i return View instead preserving my ModelView.

I hope you can help me with that,
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Please show some code. 2) Why do you need to use return View()? Please elaborate what you're trying to do.

Comment: why do you _need_ to use `return View(...)`? It sounds like you want to use the redirect.

Comment: what are you going to do with the id in your view ?

Comment: I modified the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

The route parameter is used for requests, not responses. Unless you redirect the user as part of your response, which turns out to be a new request.

If you want to return a `View` then pass any info you need as part of the model or in the `ViewBag`.
If you would like to reuses existing code (e.g. another action), then you will need to redirect with `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit to the question, I would say that the real issue is the state of the application. So instead of passing data between from request to request, use the Session object to store temporary results.